# Author's code works but mine doesn't [Kivy]

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm learning from a book about making apps with Kivy and there's this block of code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TestApp(App):
    press_count = 1
    def button_press(self, button_pressed):
        print('Button Pressed', TestApp.press_count, 'TImes')
        TestApp.press_count += 1

    def build(self):
        my_btn = Button(text='Click Me')
        my_btn.bind(on_press=TestApp.button_press)
        textinput = TextInput(text='Data Inside TextInput')
        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        box_layout.add_widget(widget=my_btn)
        box_layout.add_widget(widget=textinput)
        return box_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

when I run this I get understandably `TypeError: button_press() missing 1 required positional argument: 'button_pressed'` my question is why the author of the book isn't getting this error and the code runs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 my_btn.bind(on_press=TestApp.button_press)
```

This is wrong, it should be `my_btn.bind(on_press=self.button_press)`.

Comment: You're right. It's a mistake in the book. Using `self` fixed it.